# How to style an element as if it were appearing from the bottom of the browser window in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to have a div appear from the bottom of the browser window using inline styles in reactjs. The functionality is similar to that of the snackbar in material-ui (it pops from the bottom). The internet has been woefully inadequate on this, all I get is the solution for how to make elements scroll to you browser window. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you at least attempted this? Do you have code you can share? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide the code you have, in order to be able to iterate on that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do so with CSS transitions. When the class `test` is added to the element, it transitions the `bottom` CSS property over 2 seconds.

```js
function go() {
  document.getElementById("example").className += " test";
}
```

```css
#example {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: bottom 2s linear;
}

#example.test {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  Hello, World
</div>

<button onclick="go()">Show</button>
```